# Google+ login redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-plus

I'm trying to implement one-time code sign in flow in my system. 
Application contains of two parts:
1)Android application which requests Google+ for one-time authorization code
2)Rails server that receives one-time code from android application in request header and tries to exchange code for `access_token` and `id_token` from Google+

The problem is that everything works well if I get one-time code using JavaScript sign-in button in browser, but doesn't work when one-time code is obtained by Android application and then sent to my server.

I'm getting always

```
"error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
```

My server settings are following:

```
{ "web":
 { "client_id": "MY_REGISTERED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID",
   "client_secret": "MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "redirect_uris": ["postmessage"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

Now, how I'm requesting one-time code from Android app:
I use the same `MY_REGISTERED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID` as on my server for requesting one-time code. I don't know, maybe I have to use on Android another client id, that corresponds to my Android application? But all found documentation and articles are pointing to registered 
Web app `client_id`.

Or maybe my rails server should be configured not for web, but for installed type of registered in Google Console apps?

Now regarding `redirect_uris`. 
I've tried to set several `redirect_uris` in Google Console:

- empty field
- `http://localhost:5000`
- `https://localhost:5000`
- `http://my.deployment.url/auth2callback`

Web origins in Google console are set to 
 - `http://my.deployment.url`
 - `http://localhost:5000`

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Actually I don't understand why I need to set this `redirect_uris` values, since I don't want to have callbacks from Google, I just want to get `access_token` and use it for accessing Google+.

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I do have the exact same issue.

Comment: @siyb try to set `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` as value of the `redirect_uri` param. I did it now and it works!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the redirect_uri your android app is using to create the initial login flow is different from the redirect_uri the server is using when it tries to excange the code for an access_token. The redirect_uri the user returns to and the redirect_uri used in the token exchange must match.

Comment: Thank you, then another question arised - where can I find redirect_uri value in my android app? I don't set it explicitly. I'm using the flow as described here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app

Comment: It looks like Google actually requires there be no redirect_uri. Have a look at [these docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth#offlineAccess) and see if they help.

Comment: Thank you so much @abraham, you saved me. A lot of other answers in a lot of other questions mentioned using "postmessage" and before using this, I didn't have anything, but I was using the downloaded json file from the developer console, and that set the redirectUri. so I stopped using the json file, and removed the calls to setRedirectUri and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The proper `redirect_uri` in this case is `"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"`

Comment: More details as to why would be useful.

Comment: But Web Application does not support redirect_uri without scheme http or https, shoud I fill "http://localhost" in it?